# Having trouble to display Average sales including the Region with no sales

Tags: sql, null, case, aggregate-functions

**Having trouble to display the output including the Region with no sales.**

An insurance company maintains records of sales made by its employees. Each employee is assigned to a state. States are grouped under regions. The following tables contain the data:

```
TABLE regions
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

TABLE states
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  regionId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES regions(id)

TABLE employees
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  stateId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES states(id)

TABLE sales
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  amount INTEGER NOT NULL
  employeeId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES employees(id)
```

Management requires a comparative region sales analysis report.

Write a query that returns:

```
The region name.
Average sales per employee for the region (Average sales = Total sales made for the region / Number of employees in the region).
The difference between the average sales of the region with the highest average sales, and the average sales per employee for the region (average sales to be calculated as explained above).
```

A region with no sales should be also returned. Use 0 for average sales per employee for such a region when calculating the 2nd and the 3rd column.

**This is the code as far:**

```
SELECT regions.name, 
(CASE WHEN sales.amount<>0 THEN SUM(sales.amount)/COUNT(employees.id)ELSE 0 end)
AS average_sale,
(CASE WHEN sales.amount<>0 THEN SUM(sales.amount)/COUNT(employees.id)-MAX(sales.amount) ELSE 0 end) 
AS Diff
FROM regions
JOIN states
ON states.regionId = regions.Id
JOIN employees
ON states.id=employees.stateId
JOIN sales
ON employees.id=sales.employeeId
GROUP BY regions.Id;
```

Comment: provide data and provide expected result

Answer (score 6):

If you have reached this post from [here](https://www.testdome.com/questions/sql/regional-sales-comparison/40107?visibility=3&skillId=17), we need to have a query that will pass all the edge cases. The most important thing is: "Employees can have multiple sales."

**Average sales per employee for the region (Average sales = Total sales made for the region / Number of employees in the region).**

Remember we are getting multiple sales done by each employee.  So we need to count the number of employees in the region accurately. A distinct count of employees will give us the correct value and the average sales per employee will be accurate as well.

Left join, so that we get NULL values for some employee sales, that gives us regions with no sales, which will be displayed as zero.

So let's give a try:

```
with SalesAvg as (
  select R.name as rgn, 
    CASE WHEN SUM(IFNULL(SL.amount,0)) = 0 THEN 0                    /*region with no sales returning 0*/
    ELSE  SUM(IFNULL(SL.amount,0)) / COUNT(DISTINCT E.id) END as average             
/*distinct employee count gives the correct value for number of employees in ther region.*/
  from regions R
    left join states S on R.id = S.regionId
    left join employees E on S.id = E.stateId
    left join sales SL on E.id = SL.employeeId
  group by R.Id, R.name
) 
select 
  rgn, 
  average,
  (select max(average) from SalesAvg)- average as difference        /*highest average sales -region average*/
from SalesAvg
group by rgn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with c as (
select sum(sales.amount)/count(employee.id) as average from regions region1
left join states state on region1.id = state.regionId
left join employees employee on state.id = employee.stateId
left join sales sales on sales.employeeId = employee.id 
group by region1.id)

select region.name, 
(case when sum(sales.amount)<>0 then sum(sales.amount)/count(employee.id) else 0 end) 
as average, 
(case when sum(sales.amount)<>0 then (select max(average) from c) -     
(sum(sales.amount)/count(employee.id))  
else (select max(average) from c) end) 
as difference
from regions region
left  join states state on region.id = state.regionId
left  join employees employee on state.id = employee.stateId
left  join sales sales on sales.employeeId = employee.id
group by region.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select regions.name, avg(coalesce(sales.amount,0)) as average
from regions
left join states
on regions.id=states.regionId
left join employees 
on states.id=employees.stateId
left join sales
on employees.id=sales.employeeid
group by (regions.name)
order by avg(sales.amount)  desc
```

Comment: This doesn't show the column:

The difference between the average sales of the region with the highest average sales, and the average sales per employee for the region (average sales to be calculated as explained above).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.name, 
   COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE(s.amount, 0)), 0)/COALESCE(COUNT(e.Name), 0) AS avg_amount,
    ABS(COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE(s.amount, 0)), 0)/COALESCE(COUNT(e.Name), 0) -
(SELECT MAX(amount)
FROM
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(s.amount), 0)/COALESCE(COUNT(e.Name), 0) AS amount
    FROM sales s
    JOIN employees e
    ON s.employeeid = e.Id
    JOIN states st
    ON st.id = e.stateid
    JOIN regions r
    ON r.id = st.regionid
    GROUP BY r.name))) AS diff
FROM  sales s
JOIN employees e
ON s.employeeid = e.Id
JOIN states st
ON st.id = e.stateid
JOIN regions r
ON r.id = st.regionid
GROUP BY r.name
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH c AS (
  SELECT regions.name AS name,
  (CASE WHEN sales.amount <> 0
    THEN SUM(sales.amount) / COUNT(employees.id) 
   ELSE 0 END) AS average
  FROM regions 
    LEFT JOIN states ON regions.id = states.regionid
    LEFT JOIN employees ON states.id = employees.stateId 
    LEFT JOIN sales ON employees.id = sales.employeeid
GROUP BY regions.id)

SELECT name, 
    average,
    (SELECT MAX(average) FROM c) - average as difference
FROM c
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Can you also provide an explanation?

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
with D as(
select regions.name as name, 
    case when sum(coalesce(sales.amount,0)) = 0 then 0
   else sum(coalesce(sales.amount,0))/count( distinct employees.id)
```

end as average
from regions
left join states
on regions.id=states.regionId
left join employees
on states.id=employees.stateId
left join sales
on employees.id=sales.employeeid
group by (regions.name)
order by avg(sales.amount))
select name,
average,
(select max(average) from D)-average as difference
from D;

Answer (score 0):

```
with sales_per_region as 
(
    select regions.name , COALESCE(sum(amount)/count(employees.id),0) as average
    from regions
    left join states on regions.id = states.regionId
    left join employees on states.id = employees.stateId
    left join sales on employees.id = sales.employeeId
    group by 1
),
max_sales_per_region as 
(
  select max(average) as max_average_sales
  from sales_per_region
)
select name, average, max_average_sales-average as difference
from sales_per_region,max_sales_per_region
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve this question and was stuck at it for a long time. Approached one of the experts and got the suggestion to use distinct count of employees. That changed the game .

```
select region_name as name,avg_sales as average ,(max_sales-avg_sales ) as difference from 
(
with 
cte as (
select r.name as region_name,
coalesce((sum(ss.amount)/count(distinct e.id)),0) as avg_sales
from regions r 
left join states s on r.id=s.regionId
left join employees e on s.id=e.stateId
left join sales ss on e.id=ss.employeeId
group by r.name
      ) 
  
select region_name,avg_sales,
case 
  when avg_sales>=0 then (select max(avg_sales) from cte) end as max_sales 
 from cte 
)x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way in mysql

```
with sales_avg AS (
    select r.name as region, 
    case when sum(ifnull(s.amount,0)) = 0 then 0
    else sum(ifnull(s.amount,0))/count(distinct e.id) end as average
    from regions r
    left join states st on r.id = st.regionid
    left join employees e on st.id = e.stateid
    left join sales s on e.id = s.employeeid
    group by r.id, r.name)
 
select region, average, (select max(average) from sales_avg) - average as difference
from sales_avg
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in MS SQL:

```
WITH sales_avg AS (
    SELECT 
        r.name AS region, 
        CASE
            WHEN SUM(ISNULL(s.amount,0)) = 0 THEN
                0
            ELSE 
                SUM(ISNULL(s.amount,0))/COUNT(distinct e.id)
        END AS average    
    FROM regions r
    LEFT JOIN states st 
        ON r.id = st.regionid
    LEFT JOIN employees e 
        ON st.id = e.stateid
    LEFT JOIN sales s 
        ON e.id = s.employeeid
    GROUP BY r.id, r.name)
```

```
    SELECT 
        region, 
        average, 
        (
            (SELECT MAX(average) FROM sales_avg) - average
        ) AS difference
    FROM sales_avg
    GROUP BY region, average
```

Answer (score 0):

it's only pass 3/4 tests :c
All regions have sales, employees have zero to many sales: Wrong answer

```
  WITH c AS (SELECT ISNULL(AVG(sales.amount),0) as avg_list
    from regions
    LEFT JOIN states ON regions.id = states.regionId
    LEFT JOIN employees ON states.id = employees.stateId
    LEFT JOIN sales ON employees.id = sales.employeeId
    GROUP BY regions.name)
    
    SELECT regions.name, ISNULL(AVG(sales.amount),0) AS averege, 
    ((SELECT max(avg_list) from c) - ISNULL(AVG(sales.amount),0)) as difference
    from regions
    LEFT JOIN states ON regions.id = states.regionId
    LEFT JOIN employees ON states.id = employees.stateId
    LEFT JOIN sales ON employees.id = sales.employeeId
    GROUP BY regions.name;
```